# Wordpress media library won't lead media due to custom theme issues

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I recently updated WordPress 4.9.6 and suddenly the Media Library stopped showing my media. I am not able to upload files either.

I started researching the possible reasons and I found out that the one and only cause is my custom theme. I logged php and javascript and fixed every issue and warning. 
Still, the media library won't work. **What are the possible reasons behind it?**

[Here is the blog](https://www.greekgeek.gr/)

Comment: no PHP errors? maybe you can try [debugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: I did. No problems at all. This is confusing.

Comment: Did you have a custom functions.php file? Any specifics functions?

Comment: @jjj You saved my day. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jjj's comment I found out what the issue was.

I wrote a custom plugin ... in functions.php (not clever). This led me to think that the problem lies in my custom theme (which partly was right cause the issue was in functions.php, even though the plugin had no reason to be in there).

I removed it, and now everything works fine. I am still not sure why nothing showed in the php error log though.

Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help ;-)